# Failed opening required 'PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php'

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I have a fresh install of `20.04`, `php 7` and have just ran `apt install phpmyadmin` followed all the procedures and now when navigating to `localhost/phpmyadmin` I am seeing:

```
[Sun Aug 08 14:51:58.410439 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 84550] [client 93.115.195.232:6537] PHP Warning:  require_once(PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/autoload.php on line 2
[Sun Aug 08 14:51:58.410486 2021] [php7:error] [pid 84550] [client 93.115.195.232:6537] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php' (include_path='/usr/share/phpmyadmin') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/autoload.php on line 2
```

This is what my `autoload.php` file looks like:

```
<?php
require_once 'PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php';
require_once 'PhpMyAdmin/ShapeFile/autoload.php';
require_once 'PhpMyAdmin/SqlParser/autoload.php';
require_once 'Symfony/Component/ExpressionLanguage/autoload.php';
require_once 'phpseclib/autoload.php';
require_once 'Twig/autoload.php';
require_once 'Twig-Extensions/autoload.php';
require_once 'ReCaptcha/autoload.php';
require_once 'Psr/Container/autoload.php';
@include_once 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
```

I openly have no idea what `PhpMyAdmin` references to?

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1560 Mar 21  2020 ajax.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 44058 Aug  8 15:02 autoload.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1750 Mar 21  2020 browse_foreigners.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3194 Mar 21  2020 changelog.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   856 Mar 21  2020 chk_rel.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4516 Mar 21  2020 config.sample.inc.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5674 Mar 21  2020 db_central_columns.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5878 Mar 21  2020 db_datadict.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  7706 Mar 21  2020 db_designer.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   271 Mar 21  2020 db_events.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4631 Mar 21  2020 db_export.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   899 Mar 21  2020 db_import.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1038 Mar 21  2020 db_multi_table_query.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  9860 Mar 21  2020 db_operations.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4859 Mar 21  2020 db_qbe.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   365 Mar 21  2020 db_routines.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1997 Mar 21  2020 db_search.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   746 Mar 21  2020 db_sql_autocomplete.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   485 Mar 21  2020 db_sql_format.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   952 Mar 21  2020 db_sql.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1011 Mar 21  2020 db_structure.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4415 Mar 21  2020 db_tracking.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   273 Mar 21  2020 db_triggers.php
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  8 14:50 doc/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4608 Mar 21  2020 error_report.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 15919 Mar 21  2020 export.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 22486 Mar 21  2020 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 15984 Mar 21  2020 gis_data_editor.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 23976 Mar 21  2020 import.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3463 Mar 21  2020 import_status.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 20259 Mar 21  2020 index.php
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Aug  8 14:50 js/
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Aug  8 14:50 libraries/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   894 Mar 21  2020 license.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1430 Mar 21  2020 lint.php
drwxr-xr-x  47 root root  4096 Aug  8 14:50 locale/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   311 Mar 21  2020 logout.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2309 Mar 21  2020 navigation.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4143 Mar 21  2020 normalization.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   507 Mar 21  2020 phpinfo.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   740 Mar 21  2020 phpmyadmin.css.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2493 Mar 21  2020 prefs_forms.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 14356 Mar 21  2020 prefs_manage.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1594 Mar 21  2020 prefs_twofactor.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1213 Mar 21  2020 print.css
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   653 Mar 21  2020 schema_export.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   785 Mar 21  2020 server_binlog.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   818 Mar 21  2020 server_collations.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   798 Mar 21  2020 server_databases.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   784 Mar 21  2020 server_engines.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1085 Mar 21  2020 server_export.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   634 Mar 21  2020 server_import.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   784 Mar 21  2020 server_plugins.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 14184 Mar 21  2020 server_privileges.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2432 Mar 21  2020 server_replication.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   698 Mar 21  2020 server_sql.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   862 Mar 21  2020 server_status_advisor.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2962 Mar 21  2020 server_status_monitor.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   897 Mar 21  2020 server_status.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1879 Mar 21  2020 server_status_processes.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1423 Mar 21  2020 server_status_queries.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1562 Mar 21  2020 server_status_variables.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1872 Mar 21  2020 server_user_groups.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   798 Mar 21  2020 server_variables.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1089 Mar 21  2020 show_config_errors.php
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug  8 14:50 sql/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  6352 Mar 21  2020 sql.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3754 Mar 21  2020 tbl_addfield.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  6334 Mar 21  2020 tbl_change.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   972 Mar 21  2020 tbl_chart.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3365 Mar 21  2020 tbl_create.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2431 Mar 21  2020 tbl_export.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   999 Mar 21  2020 tbl_find_replace.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1763 Mar 21  2020 tbl_get_field.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1540 Mar 21  2020 tbl_gis_visualization.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   684 Mar 21  2020 tbl_import.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1401 Mar 21  2020 tbl_indexes.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 15446 Mar 21  2020 tbl_operations.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   452 Mar 21  2020 tbl_recent_favorite.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2375 Mar 21  2020 tbl_relation.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 16972 Mar 21  2020 tbl_replace.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5005 Mar 21  2020 tbl_row_action.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1130 Mar 21  2020 tbl_select.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1176 Mar 21  2020 tbl_sql.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2042 Mar 21  2020 tbl_structure.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5797 Mar 21  2020 tbl_tracking.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   141 Mar 21  2020 tbl_triggers.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1049 Mar 21  2020 tbl_zoom_select.php
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4096 Aug  8 14:50 templates/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Aug  8 14:50 themes/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   956 Mar 21  2020 themes.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1910 Mar 21  2020 transformation_overview.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4617 Mar 21  2020 transformation_wrapper.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1296 Mar 21  2020 url.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1934 Mar 21  2020 user_password.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1085 Mar 21  2020 version_check.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  6604 Mar 21  2020 view_create.php
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3866 Mar 21  2020 view_operations.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on a Ubuntu 20.04 with a PHP 7.4.3.
The module autoload.php is located in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/ but this path is unknown by PHP (in your case the include path have only this as per your error message: include_path='/usr/share/phpmyadmin').

To fix this I edited the php include_path in the php.ini file in (/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini) so that it includes /usr/share/php/ at the end. e.g:

> include_path =
> ".:/php/includes:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/lib/php/**:/usr/share/php/**"

(i just added :/usr/share/php/ to my existing include_path string)

Then after a restart of the apache server my phpmyadmin page loaded properly

Comment: This way is not working on my side with PHP 8.0.25.
On my side, I don't need to change anything if I use PHP 7.x but when I switch to PHP 8.x, tried to following this solving, the problem is still there.
Any body have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me since I had an old Apache configuration (I was restoring from Debian 11 to Ubuntu 22.04).

I needed:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    # limit libapache2-mod-php to files and directories necessary by pma
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/:/usr/share/javascript/
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```